# AS400: How to know which program create a file?

Tags: sql-server, ibm-midrange, rpg

I am not expert about **AS400**, just know some commands and i exporti some files from AS400 (iSeries) into SQL Server 2005.

Actually i need to know which RPG Program created a file in a library. This because that file contains statistic data from other files stored in other AS400 libraries.

This screenshot show the file `STTMVF` in the library `DAT_4DWH` (by `DSPLIB DAT_4DWH`)

[image]

**So there are a command that let me know which RPG program created the file STTMVF ?**

If yes i need to open the source RPG or CL and try to understand which phisical files are used to compose this statistic file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [journal management](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzaki/rzakikickoff.htm) or [program references](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/ddp/rbal1progref.htm) to determine what is writing to the file.

---

## Journal management

### Starting the journal

To create a basic journal you need to create a journal receiver, a journal, and activate journalling for the file.  Replace *RECEIVER-LIB*, *RECEIVER-FILE*, *JOURNAL-LIB*, *JOURNAL-FILE*, *FILE-LIB* and *FILE* with values appropriate for your system.

```
CRTJRNRCV JRNRCV(RECEIVER-LIB/RECEIVER-FILE)
CRTJRN JRN(JOURNAL-LIB/JOURNAL-FILE) JRNRCV(RECEIVER-LIB/RECEIVER-FILE)
STRJRNPF FILE(FILE-LIB/FILE) JRN(JOURNAL-LIB/JOURNAL-FILE) OMTJRNE(*OPNCLO)
```

### Dumping the journal

```
DSPJRN JRN(JOURNAL-LIB/JOURNAL-FILE) FILE(FILE-LIB/FILE) RCVRNG(*CURCHAIN) JRNCDE(R) ENTTYP(PT PX DL UP) OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) OUTFILFMT(*TYPE1) OUTFILE(QTEMP/QADSPJRN)
```

### Querying the journal

The field `JOPGM` will contain the program name that inserted, updated, or deleted records from the file.

### Removing the journal

```
ENDJRNPF FILE(FILE-LIB/FILE)
DLTJRN JRN(JOURNAL-LIB/JOURNAL-FILE)
```

---

## Program references

### Dumping the references

```
DSPPGMREF PGM(*ALLUSR/*ALL) OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) OUTFILE(QTEMP/QADSPPGM)
```

### Querying the references

Search the file for all references where the field `WHFNAM` equals *FILE*.  The field `WHPNAM` will contain the program name.  Due to file overrides, etc this method is not as accurate as using a journal.